# Monitoring physical disk health in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

The title is pretty self explanatory really! How can I trigger an email if physical disk health degrades? Also as a side point, how can I do similar for software raid or zfs array health?

Comment: Have you done any research on this before asking here? there are lots of ways to do this ([`smartmon` tools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) for physical disks, software RAID has its own tools for checking status, hardware RAID is usually exposed through IPMI or a vendor-supplied SNMP extension), but you'll have to write some code to make it work in your specific environment...

Comment: @voretaq7 is correct. smartmon is the dead simple way to get started ( http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/monitoring-hard-disks-smart?page=0,2 ) but this is also one of the first things you find if you google around for resources on monitoring disk health.

Comment: You are asking two questions in this post, and they will have two different answers (Physical disk health vs Software RAID/ZFS health). Perhaps break them up into two different posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on a variety of things.  Many raid-controllers have their own tools to query this kind of information;

- HP's SmartArray-controllers use HP's `hpacucli`-tool.  I would in general recommend using [this nagios plugin](http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_hpasm/) for checking the health of those disks, and HP server health in general.
- DELL's servers have their own `openmanage`-drivers that needs to be queried.  A good Nagios-plugin for this is to be found [here](http://folk.uio.no/trondham/software/check_openmanage.html).
- If your harddrives support S.M.A.R.T (I believe all of them nowadays do), you can use [check_smartmon](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Uncategorized/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_smartmon/details).

Both of the above check RAID-status as well as physical drives.  In some cases, if you make sure to update the plugins now and then - you will also be told when it's appropriate to update your firmware.

- For software RAID in Linux, [check_md_adm](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Uncategorized/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_md_raid/details) can be used.
- There's a plugin for monitoring ZFS-pools on Nagios Exchange: [link](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Solaris/check_zfs/details).

Comment: For ZFS run `zpool status -x`. It will either output `all pools are healthy.` or the pool info (similar to the output of `zpool list`) if there are any detected errors.

Answer (score 2):

Use Smartmontools with Ubuntu. The following is a good tutorial, and I used this on my home desktop machine. Since this is a desktop, I use GSmartControl which provides a nice interface.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

For my production servers (which are not Ubuntu), I still use Smartmontools. It's archaic, but the best thing available.

Comment: Fun note: My system failed a month after this post. The failure was not detected by Smartmontools because the failure was a bug in the filesystem (Btrfs on Ubuntu 12.04, which was not production worthy). A learning opportunity.